# Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax;

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I get this error

> (Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access
>   violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax;)

I know it's regarding the code below as I get this error code in my console

> ([Tue Jan 21 21:32:11.564497 2020] [proxy_fcgi:error] [pid 14681:tid
>   140542562248448] [client 81.226.126.93:39132] AH01071: Got error 'PHP
>   message: PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[42000]:
>   Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL
>   syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server
>   version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE rakel IN ('3
>   31-1710')' at line 1 in
>   /var/www/vhosts/stockholmblaljusklan.se/httpdocs/cad/assets/includes/utl/larm.php:144\nStack
>   trace:\n#0
>   /var/www/vhosts/stockholmblaljusklan.se/httpdocs/cad/assets/includes/utl/larm.php(144):
>   PDOStatement->execute(Array)\n#1
>   /var/www/vhosts/stockholmblaljusklan.se/httpdocs/cad/sos/index.php(37):
>   include('/var/www/vhosts...')\n#2 {main}\n  thrown in
>   /var/www/vhosts/stockholmblaljusklan.se/httpdocs/cad/assets/includes/utl/larm.php
>   on line 144', referer:
>   https://stockholmblaljusklan.se/cad/sos/index.php)

Someone that knows how to solve this problem? Much appreciated!

```
if(isset($_POST['submit_units'])){
$units = $_POST['enheter'];
$units_2 = implode(", ", $units);

$query_3 = "UPDATE larm SET enheter=:enheter WHERE id=:id";
$stmt = $db->prepare($query_3);
$stmt->bindparam(":enheter",$units_2);
$stmt->bindparam(":id",$id);
$stmt->execute();

$enheter_3 = explode(", ", $units_2);
$count_2 = str_repeat('?,', count($enheter_3) - 1) . '?';

$query_4 = "UPDATE fordon SET on_call=$id WHERE rakel IN ($count_2)";
$stmt = $db->prepare($query_4);
$stmt->execute($enheter_3);
}
```

Comment: You never set `$id`.

Comment: Did you try `echo $query_4` to see if it looked correct?

Comment: You should use a parameter instead of substituting the `$id` variable.

Comment: Why are you creating `$units_2` by imploding `$units` and then creating `$enheter_3` by exploding that? Just do `$enheter_3 = $units;`

Comment: Why did you use parameters in the first query (which is good) but not in the second (which is not so good)? You obviously know how to do it right.

Answer (score 0):

I was not sure how to add all the below points in readable form in comments, so I am adding it here in the Answer section. Have a look at the below points:

1. `$id` not set
2. `$stmt` not closed after completing the query
3. You did not set `$id` for 2nd query
4. Comment out `$enheter_3 = explode(", ", $units_2); $count_2 = str_repeat('?,', count($enheter_3) - 1) . '?';` 
   and you can directly use `$count_2 = str_repeat('?,', count($_POST['enheter']) - 1) . '?';`
5. Your last query is susceptible to the [SQL injection attack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/601300/what-is-sql-injection)